# wxPython can't properly position a matplotlib block

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython

I've taken the code to draw a rectangle over image form [here](https://github.com/ashokfernandez/wxPython-Rectangle-Selector-Panel/blob/master/RectangleSelectorPanel.py), and modified it a little bit to suite my purposes. The only problem I have, it doesn't appear to be full screen, even though I make `fr.ShowFullScreen(True)`. There is a grey area around the image.
Edited code is below (the rectangle part is not relevant):

```
# Use the wxPython backend of matplotlib
import matplotlib       
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

# Matplotlib elements used to draw the bounding rectangle
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

# wxPython stuff for the demo
import wx

class RectangleSelectImagePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, pathToImage=None):

        # Initialise the parent
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # Intitialise the matplotlib figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(20,15), dpi=80)

        # Create an axes, turn off the labels and add them to the figure
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.axes.set_axis_off() 

        # Add the figure to the wxFigureCanvas
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        # Sizer to contain the canvas
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def setImage(self, pathToImage):
        '''Sets the background image of the canvas'''

        import matplotlib.image as mpimg

        # Load the image into matplotlib
        image = matplotlib.image.imread(pathToImage)
        # left in as anchor for image size
        self.imageSize = image.shape[0:2]
        print self.imageSize
# 
        # Add the image to the figure and redraw the canvas. Also ensure the aspect ratio of the image is retained.
        self.axes.imshow(image, interpolation="quadric", aspect='auto')
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create an demo application
    app = wx.App()

    # Create a frame and a RectangleSelectorPanel
    fr = wx.Frame(None, title='test')
    panel = RectangleSelectImagePanel(fr)

    # Set the image in the panel
    from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
    imgpath = get_sample_data('logo2.png', asfileobj=False)
    panel.setImage(imgpath)

    # Start the demo app
    fr.ShowFullScreen(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Is this question dead/solved for you? If not, post your solution or ask for one (I thought the answer should be obvious now).

Answer (score 0):

probably what you need is subplots_adjust.

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
imgpath = get_sample_data('logo2.png', asfileobj=False)
image = matplotlib.image.imread(imgpath)

imshow(image, aspect='auto')
subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

This will produce a plot that has no margin around the image.

So, if you put

```
self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0, wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

after imshow line, you will get something closer to what you need.

Then, you will probably have to adjust the figsize parameter too. for my 1920 x 1080 display, I will need 1920.0/80 inch by 1080.0/80 inch so (24,13.5)